# dependency injection not working anymore ionic2

Tags: ionic2

dependency injection dont work anymore in ionic 2

```js
import {Page, Platform, NavController} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
import {Signup} from '../signup/signup';
import {Pass} from '../pass/pass'


@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
})
export class Login {
constructor(platform: Platform, nav: NavController){

}

goTosignup(){
  this.nav.push(Signup)
}


}
```

this is what i'm doing who where working perfectly before today, today i get this error in the console

ERROR in ./app/pages/login/login.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/ondondacarrel/Desktop/code/code2/jobandgo/app/pages/login/login.js: Unexpected token (10:20)
   8 | })
   9 | export class Login {

> 10 | constructor(platform: Platform, nav: NavController){
>        |                     ^
>     11 | 
>     12 | }
>     13 |

constructor(@Inject(NavController) nav: NavController) doesn't work too , if someone can help me figure out this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was an issue related to typescript parameter decoration and javascript parameter decoration

```js
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
import {Signup} from '../signup/signup';
import {Pass} from '../pass/pass'

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
})

export class Login {
  static get parameters() {
   return [[NavController]];
 }
constructor(nav){
this.nav = nav
}

gotoPage(){
  this.nav.push(Signup)
}





}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try with @Inject() as shown below:

```
import {Page, Platform, NavController} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
import {Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {Signup} from '../signup/signup';
import {Pass} from '../pass/pass'


@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
})
export class Login {
constructor(@Inject(Platform) platform: Platform, @Inject(NavController) nav: NavController){

}

goTosignup(){
  this.nav.push(Signup)
}


}
```

Comment: already tried this , its not working too , Unexpected token error for the @